# macro in MS Word document is not automatically run

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote this code, it should run when the Enter key is pressed. However its not happening.
As I know I need to put this code on this "ThisDocument"[image: [clipping of a Windows Explorer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWolr.png)]

```
Private Sub Document_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
        ' This code will run when the Enter key is pressed
        MsgBox "Enter key pressed"
    End If
End Sub
```

I wrote this code and tried to run.

Comment: The Word document has no `KeyPress`-event

Comment: does word document has a event when some changes was done in this document ?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338375/what-events-can-i-use-to-monitor-users-typing-in-word: **Word provides no events for capturing the user's typing.**

Answer (score 0):

> does word document has a event when some changes was done in this document ?

Yes. You have to use the class module to initiate [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.documentchange), not ThisDocument object. And there is no event name **Document_KeyPress**, because the Word Document object is not MS Form object. You can refer to [Application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application) and [Using events with the Application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/using-events-with-the-application-object-word) for further info. For the implementation example, you can refer to my answers also. like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76381701/ms-word-vba-to-check-for-empty-text-form-fields-upon-file-close-exit).

[image]